# How can I grab the text value from content in tiptap react (typescript) wysiwyg?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tiptap

I am trying to grab the text that is typed into the wysiwig to store it into my database.

I have tried a lot of different stuff and this was my most recent iteration:

```
<EditorContent editor={editor} className="contentInput" style={{ backgroundColor:'lightgrey' }} value={state.content} onChange={(evt) => setState({ ...state, content: evt.target.value })}/>
```

and with that I am getting the error that value is not a property on target. I believe this is because it is no longer an HTML input element, but I am not sure how I would now grab that content to put in the database?

Comment: have you tried this https://www.tiptap.dev/guide/output#listening-for-changes

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I did not, I ended up moving on and going with React-page as my wysiwyg

Answer (score 9):

```
const editor = useEditor({
    // ...
    onUpdate({ editor }) {
        setState(editor.getJSON());
    },
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 5):

First you need to create a state with useState hook, then create the editor with useEditor Hook, inside it you're going to to add event onUpdate and set the value of the editorContent state on every update on the editor.

```
  const [editorContent, setEditorContent] = useState("");
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: "<p>Hello World! ️</p>",
    onUpdate({ editor }) {
      setEditorContent(editor.getHTML());
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const msg = editor?.getText();

console.log("msg", msg);
```

In console you'll get the normal text which is written in tiptap input field.

Use optional chaining because editor initially return null and you might get error of not reading value of undefined.

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help

```
onUpdate: ({ editor }: { editor: any }) => {
      if (editor) {
        const value =
          editor.contentComponent.editorContentRef.current.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
        onChange(value);
      }
    },
```

Comment: This answer is a convoluted way of getting the text value for an HTML element that already has a way to access it via the JS object based on the documentation